# Is there a way to return same length arrays in numpy.hist?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, plot, histogram

I'm trying to create a histogram plot in python, normalizing with some custom values the y-axis values. For this, I was thinking to do it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('foo.bar')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

hist=np.histogram(data, bins=(1.0, 1.5 ,2.0,2.5,3.0))
x=[hist[0]*5,hist[1]]
ax.plot(x[0], x[1], 'o')
```

but of course, the last line gives:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

Is there a way to force np.hist to give the same number of elements for the x[0] and x[1] arrays, for example by deleting the first or last element for one of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hist[1] contains the limits in which you have made the histogram. I guess you probably want to get the centers of those intervals, something like:

```
x = [hist[0], 0.5*(hist[1][1:]+hist[1][:-1])]
```

and then the plot should be ok, right?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it depends on your data source.

Try loading the data as a numpy array, and selecting the range of elements yourself before passing to the histogram function.

e.g.

```
dataForHistogram = data[0:100][0:100]   # Assuming your data is in this kind of structure.
```

Comment: My data file has only one column, out of which I want to make that histogram. It's not about the limits of the data themselves, but the problem lied in the fact that np.histogram gives you the bin edges and the number counts in each of them, resulting in one extra element in the array that contains the bin limits.